# python how to count number of occurences which were extracted from another input file

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
path=os.getcwd()
list_dir=os.listdir(path+'//Osativa')
if not os.path.exists('results'):
    os.makedirs('results')
fo1=open('./results/annotation.txt','w')
f1=open(path+'//CLEAN FILE.csv').readlines()
f2=open(path+'//Osativa//Osativa_323_v7.0.annotation_info.txt').readlines()
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
            print locus_id
```

my question is how to count number of locus_id which I extracted using above script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either count them as they occur, or store them in a container.

**Counting**

```
num = 0
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
            num += 1
print(num)
```

**Container**

```
ids = []
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
            ids.append(locus_id)
print(len(ids))
```

Comment: See this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module!

After reading the file, iterate through every line, get the first item(`line[1]`) and check if 'LOC' is present. Them sum the resulting list!

```
import csv
f1=open(path+'//CLEAN FILE.csv')
reader = csv.reader(f1)
print sum(1 for line in reader if 'LOC' in line[1])
```

Comment: If you feel an answer suits your question best, check the tick mark below up/down vote for each answer!